# MDX - Get the last 3 members of the selected member

Tags: mdx, performancepoint

I am pretty new with MDX so please bear with me.

I am designing an analytical chart with `PerformancePoint` in which the `bottom(X)` axis will display a date range. The displayed date range will depend on the selected value of the `date` filter, which is based on the `DATE` dimension with this hierarchy: `Year>Quarter>Month`.

Let's say the user selects `2010` from the date filter. We want the query to return the last 4 years prior to the `2010` (`2007,2008,2009,2010`). If `Q1-10` is selected, we want the last 4 quarters including `Q1-10`. If a month is selected (`Sept 2010`), we want the last 4 months (`June 2010, July 2010, Aug 2010, Sept 2010`).

I appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [LastPeriods](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145588.aspx) function:

```
LastPeriods(4, <<UniqueName>>)
```